# Is it possible to use HARDWARE JPEG decoding on Android, and if so, how?

Tags: android, android-ndk, jpeg

I'm developing an (NDK) app that needs to decode 1920x1080 JPEG images at at least 60FPS. I've compiled (for ARM NEON) and am currently using TurboJPEG which can meet this requirement for some time before the device starts getting too hot (it's not that hot, but have no explanation for why it starts slowing down, beyond that). I've developed the same app on iOS and had the same issue there (except there the phone actually did get quite hot) and resolved the issue by switching to HW/GPU JPEG decoding. I'd like to do that on Android, and have searched far and wide to find out how to do that on *any* Android device (I know *all* is not feasible) without luck.

I have used BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() and can say that it definitely doesn't use HW JPEG decoding on Samsung S7 Edge (6.1), neither is it anywhere near fast enough (~20-25FPS). I've used TurboJPEG which is fast enough but has thermal issues. I've looked into using OpenMAX IL (not public, if at all on Android) & SKIA (seems to use TurboJPEG).

Can it really be possible with JPEG decoding hardware sitting in pretty much every recent Android SoC that there is *absolutely no way* to use it???! I can't believe that, so how to use it?

Comment: `(it's not that hot, but have no explanation for why it starts slowing down, beyond that)` is as you probably surmised most likely thermal throttling. Is there a reason why 60 fps is a requirement? You might be able to live with 30fps but didn't specify the use case. It sounds like you are trying to implement MJPEG but that isn't an officially supported format in the Android Compatibility Definition Document https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#5_3_video_decoding

Comment: If your 60fps is a hard requirement, I would look at each SOC manufacturer (Qualcomm, Samsung/Exonos, nVidia, Rockchip, Mediatek, AllWinner, Intel) for SDKs which would allow access to hardware accelerated APIs. Assuming such libraries are available it would be at the price of how many platforms to support.

Comment: At least 60FPS is a hard requirement. I also want to support API level 19 (Kitkat) and up. I was hoping that there was *some* API for accelerated JPEG decoding on Android (even if only supported on high end hardware or whatever). From your answer (and the complete lack of evidence for in my searches) I must conclude that there is no HW JPEG acceleration on Android for any purpose in any version with any chipset?! That's a lot of wasted silicon (and begs the question why is it even present on the SoC)...

Comment: HW JPEG is for ODM/OEMs to implement the various parts of the Android framework stack (like SKIA) not necessarily for Android app developers to access. As no official API is presented it may just be that Google/Android saw no need as well not limit SoC manufacturers. If you think it should be in Android - you can post an appropriate Feature Request case to the Bug Tracker: https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs As I said earlier look for SoC SDKs to see if its exposed. I also wonder if a different supported video streaming protocol may suit your needs better.

Comment: I see what you mean by 'not public' regarding OpenMAX IL - https://source.android.com/devices/media/ in which case your only option may only using devices where the MJPEG codec is available (non-standard handset maker 'feature') which would be really hard given the thousands of Android handset models out there.

Comment: The 'not public' bit is not being able to use the codecs that may even be there, as only OpenMAX AL is exposed at NDK level. I guess best bet is figuring out how to do it on Exynos and Snapdragon and the remainder get limited to 1280x720, which is all NEON seems to be able to maintain for 60+ minutes @60Hz...

Comment: Not sure what to do about this, as the app needs to fit into an existing ecosystem and so can't dictate protocol changes, and needs to work on older (as well as current) versions of Android, so no amount of issue reporting is going to change anything. It seems that the way (on Samsung at least) to do HW JPEG decoding is via V4L2_M2M. However, this needs to open /dev/video*x* to do the necessary ioctls, which is blocked from NDK apps on Android >= 21 (Kitkat).

Comment: Don't know if you can just add an intermediate server(s) which would be responsible for MJPEG to supported streaming video as it sounds like you've exhausted what Android is capable of providing.

Comment: Need as close to zero latency as possible, so can't take the (minimum) 16ms hit that recoding a frame would take. Gonna keep digging...

Comment: As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546511/192373) quite a while ago, SKIA can use hardware accelerated JPEG decoder. I don't know why you established that S7 uses software for BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(). There may be other reasons why it does not deliver more than 25 FPS. I don't think you can use /dev/video*x* on unrooted devices on any platform.

Comment: Will look into SKIA again, last I looked it was using TurboJPEG on Android. Maybe I missed something. S7 uses software for decodeByteArray. How do I know? Device gets hot quickly and it's slow. Android 7.0 is faster (40-50FPS initially) than 6.0 (20-25FPS initially) for this, but still way slower than TurboJPEG. All software solutions run into thermal issues at resolutions above 1440x810 which cause them to start backing down after 30-60 seconds. HW decode on iOS can go for hours without getting warm or slowing down.

Comment: Not looking to write my own HW JPEG decoder, looking to use one. SKIA does not provide any. The only way I can see to use HW JPEG decoding on Android is via ioctls on /dev/video*x*, which doesn't seem to be possible on unrooted devices. The question is: "Is it possible to use HARDWARE JPEG decoding on Android, and if so, how?"

Comment: In any case, the SKIA library on the phone is not accessible to user code (not a public API), so you'd have to build your own, leaving behind any HW decoder the OEM/ODM provided for it.

Comment: If anyone can answer this question with a concrete example of how HW JPEG decoding can be done on an unrooted, unmodified consumer phone, that would be much appreciated. As it stands, it appears that it is not possible through any public API on Android, nor is it possible to achieve by "talking to the hardware directly", as that hardware is linked to the camera interface which is not permitted to be used from userland in Android versions >= 5.0 (which rules out building any portions of Chromium or anything else using l4v2 for this purpose).

Comment: I found a couple examples of how this can be done: https://github.com/archersmind/EncoderDecoderTestForMJPEG and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489850/android-mediacodec-decoding-mjpeg-frames

Comment: @whoKnows Thanks, those examples are useful. I implemented video/mjpeg decoding using Android MediaCodec, only to find out that there is not a single phone that supports video/mjpeg on all test devices I tried from Android 7-14.